# Eiffel: unknown identifier `cursor` on LINKED_LIST[STRING]

Tags: eiffel

I have an `unknown identifier` on the local `like some_values.cursor`, I really don't understand why!

```
qry_update_set_fields (some_keys, some_values, some_unstored_field_names: LINKED_LIST[STRING]): STRING
    require
        same_some_keys_some_values_count: some_keys.count = some_values.count
    local
        l_val_c: like some_values.new_cursor
    do
        Result := ""
        l_val_c := some_values.new_cursor
        across
            some_keys as l_key_c
        loop
            Result := l_key_c.item + "=" + l_val_c.item + ","
            l_val_c.forth
        end
        if Result.ends_with (",") then
            Result.remove_tail (1)
        end
    ensure
        dont_modify_parameters: old some_keys.is_equal (some_keys) and old some_values.is_equal (some_values)
    end
```

### working

```
l_val_c: LINKED_LIST_CURSOR [STRING]
```

### Neither working

```
l_val_c: LINKED_LIST_CURSOR [like some_values.item]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example tries using an argument in the qualified anchored type `like argument.some_feature`. This is not supported. Types, anchored to arguments, are not part of the standard Eiffel and are supported only for backward compatibility in the form `like argument`.

Comment: @Pipo There is some discrepancy between actual and formal types anchored to arguments. E.g., the formal type of the anchor can be detachable, but a client that passes an expression of an attached type, expects to see an attached anchored type (e.g., for Result). The same applies to other variants — basic, separate, expanded types... Specifying and maintaining the rules for all these cases is a bit too complicated.

Comment: Thx, whats the difference on compilation between arguments, locals and class features?